# Вывод всех возможных ip-адресов из диапазона

Tags: powershell

Нужно написать скрипт на powershell. Есть любой IP адрес сети и маска (к примеру: 10.151.96.0/21), нужно вывести все возможные ip-адреса, удовлетворяющие адресу сети и его маске. Как организовать этот цикл, чтобы работал с любым начальным условием?

Answer (score 7):

Пока суть да дело, вот код на C# накатал:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

string rangeIP = "10.151.96.0";
int rangeMask = 21;

int wildcard = 32 - rangeMask;
byte[] ipb = IPAddress.Parse(rangeIP).GetAddressBytes();
Array.Reverse(ipb);
int ip = BitConverter.ToInt32(ipb, 0);

for (int i = 1; i < (1 << wildcard) - 1; i++) {
    int ipi = ip | i;
    byte[] ipib = BitConverter.GetBytes(ipi);
    Array.Reverse(ipib);
    Console.WriteLine(new IPAddress(ipib));
}
```

Сейчас попробую PowerShell вспомнить...

Во, так получилось:

```
$rangeIP = "10.151.96.0"
$rangeMask = 21

$wildcard = (32 - $rangeMask)
$ipb = [Net.IPAddress]::Parse($rangeIP).GetAddressBytes()
[Array]::Reverse($ipb)
$ip = [BitConverter]::ToInt32($ipb, 0)

For ($i = 1; $i -lt ((1 -shl $wildcard) - 1); $i++) {
    $ipi = ($ip -bor $i)
    $ipib = [BitConverter]::GetBytes($ipi)
    [Array]::Reverse($ipib)
    Write-Host (New-Object IPAddress(@(,$ipib)))
}
```

За соответствие кода канонам не отвечаю, я PS не знаю. :)